# Central maven repository for local network

Tags: maven

Can i create a central maven repository which will be connected to internet 
and a local lan network will connect to that central repository?

Comment: sure, using http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install.html) and [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/). It will give you a kick start.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous products that will do this, most common are Nexus and [JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/), in JFrog (which is free) you can create a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) which is a combination of [Maven Repository](https://search.maven.org/) and a local repository.